# Tweepy - Efficiently querying multiple keywords from a specific user

Tags: tweepy

I have a list of Twitter users, and would like to search each user's timeline for specific keywords. I have currently done this with a full archive search using `from: screen_name`

However, the full archive search has a rate limit of 300 per every 15 minutes.

Is there a way that I can more efficiently perform this query?

```
def curated_user_tweets(screen_name):
    
    query = 'lang:en -is:retweet keyword1 from:' + screen_name + ' OR keyword2 from:' + screen_name \
            + ' OR keyword3 from:' + screen_name + ' OR keyword4 from:' + screen_name
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                     query = query, 
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text', 'conversation_id', 'attachments'],
                                     expansions = ['author_id'],
                                     start_time = '2019-05-03T00:00:00Z',
                                     end_time = '2022-07-01T00:00:00Z', max_results=500):
            time.sleep(1)
            tweets.append(response)
```

```
users = ['@screen_name1', '@screen_name2', '@screen_name3'...]
tweets = []

while True:
    try:
        for user in users:
            curated_user_tweets(user)
            print(len(tweets))
    except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
        time.sleep(60*15)
        print(e)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Is the rate limit a problem because you have a lot of users or because there are too much tweets from each user?

Comment: It is because I have a large list of users. So after every 300 users in my list, the rate limit is exceeded (because the API treats every iteration of the for loop as a separate API call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `OR` to put several screen names in the same query?

```py
query = 'lang:en -is:retweet (keyword1 OR keyword2 OR keyword3) (from:@screen_name1 OR from:@screen_name2 OR from:@screen_name3)'
```

You can easily add the `from` prefix and merge the strings from your list:

```py
users_str = ' OR '.join(['from:' + user for user in users_list])
```

Of course, queries are limited to 1024 characters, so you may not be able to search for all the users in the same query. But grouping some of them may be enough to avoid the rate limit.